# What criteria differentials an A/B/C/etc... test with a Multivariate test with respect to webpages?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, inference

I'm a software engineer with a weak background in probability and statistics. I want to determine whether the position and color of the "Purchase" buttons affects my conversion rate. I want to create a test with a control and 3 variants.

The control is the original checkout page.

Variant 1 changes the button's color but not it's location on the page.

Variant 2 changes the button's location but not the color.

Variant 3 changes the button's color and location.

I have two questions:

1. Is this a type of A/B test or Multivariate? I feel like I could justify either one.
2. Do the methods for testing the null hypothesis change between the two different types of experiments?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, A/B testing is only a marketing term for the two-sample t-test. As you have a factor variable (original checkout page) as control variable, you need multivariate regression. I would go for a logistic regression model with the binary variable "converted" as dependent y-variable, and the colour of the button and the location of the button as two independent dummy variables plus original checkout page as factor independent variable for control. Does this make sense?

Comment: For the most part it makes sense but there's a couple of things that I'm unclear on. What would the experiment have to look like to qualify it as a n-sample t-test? 3 different buttons colors but not positions?

Comment: Also, what would result would I have to look for to determine which page is the winner? I've only used logistic regression in context of machine learning (aka train a model and make predictions) and not with hypothesis testing.

Comment: A straight-forward solution for the "3-sample" t-test is simply to make 3 pairwise comparisons (I'm sure there are smarter ways, but that is not quite my area). In terms of logistic regression, just look at the coefficients. Say for instance your model is a*x_1 + b*x_2 + d*x_4 with a and b the coefficients for your button. If a is significantly positive and b is not significant, then change the colour and with location doesn't matter. If a is significantly negative and b significantly positive, don't change the colour but change the location. Probably worth to test the interaction c*x_1*x_2

Comment: Ok so the 3 pair wise comparisons are: Control v. Button Color, Control v. Button Position, and Control v. Position and Color. And each of those 3 comparisons are plugged into 1 model? or 3 models?